# (Software issue) Can anyone suggest a download that will definitely bring my Mingw32 compiler up to speed?

Tags: c++, mingw

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    string s = "wassup", newVal = "though";

    cout << *(s.insert(s.begin(), newVal.begin(), newVal.end()));

}
```

This brings up the problem that the return type of string's insert member function is void (error: void value not ignored as it ought to be). [This link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/insert/) indicates C++98 returns void but the "new" standard C++11 does indeed return an iterator.

A bit of context, I actually faced this problem earlier. I was/am using CodeBlocks (GCC Compiler Collection) on Windows 7 64-bit and this program gave the same issue (dereferencing void):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
int main(){

    list<int> x = {1,2,3,4};

    *(x.insert(++x.begin(), 3, 2));

    for(auto c : x)
        cout << c;

}
```

I posted my issue on a different forum and a user pointed out Mingw32 was missing that particular C++11 change, indicating Mingw-w64 does not have this issue. So I went straight to installing Mingw-w64 on Code::Blocks using [this](http://yzhong.co/?p=622) guide and the problem was resolved. It's only now I've found out that the overloaded function which takes three iterator parameters STILL returns void.

I'm a little confused as to why Code::Blocks Mingw32 didn't supply a fully updated C++11 standard. Can anyone suggest a download that will definitely bring my compiler up to speed?

Comment: Shouldn't the title of your post be *Can anyone suggest a download that will definitely bring my Mingw32 compiler up to speed?*

Comment: *"I'm a little confused as to why Code::Blocks Mingw32 didn't supply a fully updated C++11 standard"* Don't be upset, Visual Studio 2013 has a slew of C++11 non-compliance too :) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx

Comment: Does it work if you use `s.cbegin()` instead of `s.begin()` ?

Comment: @JonathanPotter There is no matching function with a const_iterator parameter. So it doesn't work.